# AsciiDoc includes wrong diagram

Tags: intellij-idea, asciidoc, plantuml

I am using [AsciiDoc](https://asciidoc.org/) and [Plant UML](https://plantuml.com/) in IntelliJ IDEA to write documentation.

There I have run into a strange issue with including diagrams. I have found a way to make it work, but I don't understand why. I would like to know why it works the way it does.

I am using the following statement to include a Plant UML diagram on a page:

```
["plantuml","containers"]
----
include::../diagrams/containers.puml[]
----
```

However, instead of including `../diagrams/containers.puml` as intended, this includes a different diagram from the seemingly unrelated resource of `../external-references/diagrams/external-components.puml`, and then scales it up to the size of ../diagrams/containers.puml`.

For some reason, this only happens for this one includes statement. The following inclusion of a different PUML diagram, for example, works no matter where in the AsciDoc I put it:

```
["plantuml","system-context"]
----
include::../diagrams/system-context.puml[]
----
```

Now, as mentioned before, I managed to get it to work by changing the whole statement to the following (removing `",containers"` in the header):

```
["plantuml"]
----
include::../diagrams/containers.puml[]
----
```

For me, that raises two questions:

1. Why does the include work for `system-context.puml` but not for `containers.puml`?
2. Why is it even affected by the second part of the syntax? I thought this was for alternative text if the image can't be displayed.

Comment: You can also try asking/reporting at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-intellij-plugin/issues.

Comment: Thanks. For cross reference, I created the following issue there: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-intellij-plugin/issues/388 . If that leads to a solution, I will post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Remove or change the `"containers"` argument in the square brackets.

The problem arises because there is another diagram (or file) somewhere in your project that is called `"containers"`.

As specified in the [asciidoctor docs](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/diagram-extension/latest/#creating-a-diagram) the second argument in the square brackets define a target-output-file-name (in your case `containers`). I assume that in the process of rendering plantuml diagrams asciidoctors creates and stores some image file (png, svg, or sth. like that) somewhere to embed it later.

```
["plantuml","containers"]
----
include::../diagrams/containers.puml[]
----
```

Here the "Anatomy of a diagram from the asciidoctor docs:

```
[diagram-type, target=output-file-name, format=output-format]   
.... 
Diagram in appropriate syntax
....
```

If target is omitted, a filename will be auto-generated.